# Tabela para armazenar despesas e receitas. Informações cíclicas

Tags: c#, sql-server, estrutura-de-dados

Estou criando um sistema em C# para armazenar despesas e receitas individuais. Estou com dúvidas sobre o armazenamento deste tipo de informação, que tem frequências e repetições.
Por exemplo:
Tenho uma despesa mensal por 36 meses ou
Tenho uma receita trimestral por tempo indeterminado

Qual seria o melhor jeito de armazenar estas informações pensando em minimizar o tamanho do banco e facilitar a busca por registros em um determinado período de tempo?

Minha primeira ideia é uma tabela que armazene a data de início da ocorrência, o tipo de registro (Receita ou Despesa), repetições (quantas vezes esta ocorrência se repetirá),  frequência (anual, diário, semestral,...) e valor.

Comment: já tentou desenhar um diagrama (pode ser classe/entidade) da sua ideia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Tenho uma despesa mensal por 36 meses ou tenho uma receita trimestral por tempo indeterminado. Qual seria o melhor jeito de armazenar estas informações pensando em minimizar o tamanho do banco e facilitar a busca por registros em um determinado período de tempo?

Um registro por mês. Parece não ser o mais razoável, mas vou dizer porque é.

Em primeiro lugar, históricos. Considerando ainda despesas, a complexidade da sua aplicação subiria muito se você tivesse que analisar despesas e despesas recorrentes (estou supondo que sejam duas entidades diferentes). Aqui ou você teria que proibir a alteração depois do lançamento (o que é péssimo para a aplicação e causaria estranheza ao cliente), ou auditar cada alteração e recompor todo o balanço tendo com base estas alterações, o que tornaria seu trabalho um inferno.

Em segundo lugar, consistência. Há o agravante de o usuário alterar, por exemplo, o dia em que esta despesa irá ocorrer depois de, vamos dizer, 18 meses. Se fosse apenas um registro, a alteração da data faria o sistema incorrer no problema de alterar a data de uma despesa retroativa. Isto que nem falei de valores, e nem de fechamento de meses, que são coisas comuns em sistemas de receitas e despesas. Manter esses registros inalterados após o fechamento é fundamental para a credibilidade do sistema.

## Minha primeira ideia é uma tabela que armazene a data de início da ocorrência, o tipo de registro (Receita ou Despesa), repetições (quantas vezes esta ocorrência se repetirá), frequência (anual, diário, semestral,...) e valor.

Isto funciona bem para deixar registrado ao sistema quando ele deve replicar um registro de despesa, mas não como registro definitivo da despesa de fato.

Comment: Então se eu manter minha ideia e criar outra tabela que armazena cada lançamento, eu posso criar opções para o usuário alterar toda a série ou apenas um registro. Gostei. Mas e as séries com data de término indeterminada, por exemplo, salário?

Comment: Aí salário vai ser lançado mensalmente. O lançamento recorrente não vai ter data final obrigatória.

Comment: Isso quer dizer que todo mês eu teria que planejar meu salário, aluguel, luz, água,... Estou pensando em criar uma série especial em que eu crio novos lançamentos (de acordo com as configurações da série) conforme a navegação do usuário. Por exemplo: Criei a série salário, com o valor X, mensal e sem data de término. Quando eu precisar das informações de 2020 (futuro), eu verifico se tenho que criar lançamentos deste tipo de série.

Comment: @Onaiggac Exato, mas já fica bem mais fácil do que deixar tudo numa tabela só.

Comment: Certamente. Vlw.